# why does int object is not subscriptable in my code

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to check if the code and the guess was the same and the error TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable appeared

> if guess["1"] == secret_code["1"]:
> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
>  # A secret message has been intercepted
> message = "2HFHOUWAHIFGA" # this message is gibberish
> """ This function decodes a secret message
> Input: the secret message(a string)
> Output: a boolean value """

```
print ("welcome to spaceship and aliens!")
print ("your goal is to crack a secret 4-digit code.All the digits in the code are unique.")
print ("a spaceship (S) means you've guessed the right position.")
print ("an alien (A) means you've guesed the right digit but at the wrong position")
print ("wrong digits get ignored")

secret_code = {}
secret_code["1"] = input("pick the first digit in the secret code:")
secret_code["2"] = input("pick the second digit in the secret code:")
secret_code["3"] = input("pick the third digit in the secret code:")
secret_code["4"] = input("pick the fourth digit in the secret code:")

for counter in range(100):
    print ()

guess = {}
guess["1"] = input("enter the first digit of the secret code:")
guess["2"] = input("enter the second digit of the secret code:")
guess["3"] = input("enter the third digit of the secret code:")
guess["4"] = input("enter the fourth digit of the secret code:")

# compares the player's guess to the secret code by looking at each digit, one at a time
def compare_guess(secret_code, guess):
    num_spaceship = (0)
    num_aliens = (0)
    for guess in range(4):
        if guess["1"] == secret_code["1"]:
            num_spaceship += 1
        elif guess["1"] in secret_code:
            num_aliens += 1
        if guess["2"] == secret_code["2"]:
            num_spaceship += 1
        elif guess["2"] in secret_code:
            num_aliens += 1
        if guess["3"] == secret_code["3"]:
            num_spaceship += 1
        elif guess["3"] in secret_code:
            num_aliens += 1
        if guess["4"] == secret_code["4"]:
            num_spaceship += 1
        elif guess["4"] in secret_code:
            num_aliens += 1
        result = f"{num_spaceship}S{num_aliens}A"
        return result


guess = "0000" 
while secret_code!= guess:
    result = compare_guess (secret_code, guess)
    if result == "4S0A":
        print ("congratulations, you broke the secret code")
    else:
        print (result)
```

``

Comment: After `for guess in range(4):`  variable `guess` becomes an integer and you cannot access it as dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong in your code.

There initial setup is fine. You then redefine `guess` from being a dictionary to being a string.

If you remove `guess = "0000"`, and your guess is the same as the secret code, then the `while` loop never runs. If it isn't the same, then you run into the error you're talking about because in the `compare_guess` function you further redefine `guess` as an integer.

Even if you fix the `compare_guess` function, the logic in the `while` loop doesn't allow the loop to terminate; you're comparing `secret_code` with `guess`, but never altering either `secret_code` or `guess`, so if `secret_code != guess`, then that is always true, and you enter an infinite loop.

Additionally, inside your `compare_guess` function, the return is inside the loop, meaning that it will only ever do the first iteration and then return.

To fix it:
Remove the `for` loop in the `compare_guess` function. Keep the body of the loop, just remove the `for` bit.

Make the bit where you populate the `guess` dictionary into a function called something like `make_guess`. This should return the dictionary full of guesses.

define `guess = {}` before the `while` loop

Make the first line in the `while` loop something like `guess = make_guess()`. Now you're updating the `guess` dictionary inside the loop and you'll have a chance to terminate.